# Secondary loop doesn't work

Tags: customization, loop

Hi I got a problem with my secondary loop in my template page.php.
I'm trying to display some testimonials, the code that retrieve those testimonials works perfectly fine in my index.php but I won't retrieve any testimonial if I make the call from my template page here is my code:
slideshow.php

```
<div class="jumbotron bg-black">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container experience">
      <hr>
      <h2><strong>EXPERIENCIA</strong></h2>
      <hr style="width:300px;">
      <div id="myCarousel2" style="height:250px;" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php
                $query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial','p' => $id, 'order' => 'ASC', 'showposts' => '11'));
                $i = 0;
                if($query->have_posts()):
                while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                if($i == 0) { ?>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" class="active"></li>
           <?php
                }else { ?>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>"></li>
           <?php
                }
                $i++;
                endwhile;
                else: ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'Oh God Why?' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif;
            ?>
        </ol>
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
          <?php
            $j = 0;
            if($query->have_posts()):
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            if($use_excerpt){
                 $testimonial['content'] = get_the_excerpt();
            } else {
                 $testimonial['content'] = get_the_content();
            }

            if($j == 0) { ?>
                <div class="item active" style="height:250px; width:800px;">
         <?php
            }else { ?>
                <div class="item" style="height:250px; width:800px;">
         <?php
            } ?>
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="width:800px;">
              <p> <?php echo $testimonial['content']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            $j++;
            endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my code of my template page:

```
<div class="jumbotron-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/banner/empresa.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="icon-b"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/icon-b.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
           <h2 style="text-align:center;"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-ms-4"><br><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/empresa.jpg" class="img-circle"  alt="Empresa PERCHISA Perforaciones en Chihuahua SA de CV"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-ms-8">
               <?php
                     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        the_content();
                     endwhile; else: ?>
                    <h1>No se encontraron articulos</h1>
               <?php
                    endif;
              ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

If I move the include before the main loop is executed it works, I will apreciate your help.

Comment: why is `'p' => $id` in your query arguments? where do you set `$id`?

Comment: Thank you that was the problem I'm a little embarrased right now. I apreciate a lot your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'p' => $id
```

why you this?
and if you create show all pages on your testimonial or slider show whatever

```
is_page(); use condition on footer, header, index and YOUR-TEMPLATES
```